# Setting the Admin in Administrate Gem Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have followed the [guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/286) on how to install the Administrate gem in Rails for my app but what I want to add is the ability to set the Admins only by me. I have followed the [Gtihub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/286) instructions but I am stuck on how to set my email or any other users email to be an admin. Here's what I have added so far:

**controller/admin/application_controller.rb**

```
# All Administrate controllers inherit from this `Admin::ApplicationController`,
# making it the ideal place to put authentication logic or other
# before_filters.
#
# If you want to add pagination or other controller-level concerns,
# you're free to overwrite the RESTful controller actions.
class Admin::ApplicationController < Administrate::ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authenticate_admin

  def authenticate_admin
    redirect_to '/', alert: 'Not authorized.' unless current_user && access_whitelist
  end

  private
    def access_whitelist
      current_user.try(:admin?) || current_user.try(:door_super?)
    end

  # Override this value to specify the number of elements to display at a time
  # on index pages. Defaults to 20.
  # def records_per_page
  #   params[:per_page] || 20
  # end
end
```

**dashboards/user_dashboard.rb**

```
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class UserDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  # ATTRIBUTE_TYPES
  # a hash that describes the type of each of the model's fields.
  #
  # Each different type represents an Administrate::Field object,
  # which determines how the attribute is displayed
  # on pages throughout the dashboard.
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    posts: Field::HasMany,
    reviews: Field::HasMany,
    id: Field::Number,
    email: Field::String,
    encrypted_password: Field::String,
    reset_password_token: Field::String,
    reset_password_sent_at: Field::DateTime,
    remember_created_at: Field::DateTime,
    sign_in_count: Field::Number,
    current_sign_in_at: Field::DateTime,
    last_sign_in_at: Field::DateTime,
    current_sign_in_ip: Field::String,
    last_sign_in_ip: Field::String,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime,
    name: Field::String,
    password: PasswordField,
    password_confirmation: PasswordField

  }

  # COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed on the model's index page.
  #
  # By default, it's limited to four items to reduce clutter on index pages.
  # Feel free to add, remove, or rearrange items.
  COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :posts,
    :reviews,
    :id,
    :email,
  ]

  # SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed on the model's show page.
  SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = ATTRIBUTE_TYPES.keys

  # FORM_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed
  # on the model's form (`new` and `edit`) pages.
  FORM_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :posts,
    :reviews,
    :email,
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    # :encrypted_password,
    # :reset_password_token,
    # :reset_password_sent_at,
    # :remember_created_at,
    # :sign_in_count,
    # :current_sign_in_at,
    # :last_sign_in_at,
    :current_sign_in_ip,
    :last_sign_in_ip,
    :name,
  ]

  # Overwrite this method to customize how users are displayed
  # across all pages of the admin dashboard.
  #
  # def display_resource(user)
  #   "User ##{user.id}"
  # end
end
```

Comment: would you be willing to share your app/fields/password_field.rb ? I have been looking for a way to get a custom field type for "password" fields :)

Answer (score 6):

This is how I manage access

```
# All Administrate controllers inherit from this `Admin::ApplicationController`,
# making it the ideal place to put authentication logic or other
# before_filters.
#
# If you want to add pagination or other controller-level concerns,
# you're free to overwrite the RESTful controller actions.
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < Administrate::ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_admin

    def authenticate_admin
      redirect_to root_url unless current_user.try(:admin)
    end

    # Override this value to specify the number of elements to display at a time
    # on index pages. Defaults to 20.
    # def records_per_page
    #   params[:per_page] || 20
    # end
  end
end
```

So its basically checks boolean field of `current_user` method. Create it for your user model if you don't have it, or use what authorization system offers.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do check for admin,

1-You need to add an column "admin" with type boolean to you User table.

2- add a code like the one below to your controller that you are using to verify that user is admin:

```
def authenticate_admin
  if !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry You do not have enought privilege"
  end
end
```

then right after your controller class declaration you add:

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin
```

that will verify if the user is admin or not.
make sure you use the rails console to set the admin column to true for the account you want to set as admin.

let me know how it goes..